# Python code to print directories recursively

Tags: python, macos, directory

I have the following code , but it traverses the 1st directory it finds and stops.
I feel i have the recursive function which should have given the other directories too.
Can anyone please point out what is wrong with this code.

```
def func(path,no):
    no=no+2
    for item in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isfile(path+"\\"+item):
            print no * "-" + " " + item
        if os.path.isdir(path+"\\"+item):
            path=path + "\\" + item
            print no * "-" + " " + item
            func(path,no)


path="D:\\Hello"
no=0
func(pah,no)
```

OUTPUT :

```
-- 1.txt
-- 2.txt
-- 3.txt
-- blue
---- 33.txt
---- 45.txt
---- 56.txt
---- Tere
```

"blue" & "tere" are the directories. There are more directories int the "HELLO" folder which is not printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you change the `path` value to `path + "\\" + item` when you first find a directory. Then `os.path.isfile(path+"\\"+item)` and `os.path.isdir(path+"\\"+item)` all return `False`.

It should be like this:

```
def func(path,no):
    no=no+2
    for item in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isfile(path+"\\"+item):
            print no * "-" + " " + item
        if os.path.isdir(path+"\\"+item):
            print no * "-" + " " + item
            func(path + "\\" + item,no)
```

Answer (score 5):

To walk through directories recursivly, use [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk)

```
import os

path = r'path\to\root\dir'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    # Access subdirs and files
```

---

**On another note:**

1. To join parts of a path together, use `os.path.join`. So instead of    `path+"\\"+item` you could use `os.path.join(path, item)`. This will work on all platforms, and you don't have to think about escaping slashes etc.
2. A better way to print values is to use the [`format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) method. In your case you could write

   ```
   print '{} {}'.format(no*'-', item)`
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   print no * "-" + " " + item
   ```

Comment: My code should also have printed the directories ? Can you tell me what the issue is ?

Comment: @VinodK Check out Liteye's answer. You change the path variable, and then jump deeper in the recursion. When you return from that call, path is changed, and the rest of the for loop doesn't make sense anymore.